# LINQ exception: parameter was not bound

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, exception

I received an exception while I wanted to use an included table inside a LINQ expression:

> *Exception during query materialization. The parameter was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.*

Code used:

```
var tools = toolSpecTable.Where(t => t.Operation_Id == dbOperation.Id)
                         .Include(t => t.ToolDefinitionId);

foreach (var dbTool in tools)
{
    if (dbTool.ToolDefinitionId != null)
    {
        var toolObject = toolTable
           .Where(toolObj => toolObj.ToolDefinition_Id == dbTool.ToolDefinitionId.Id)
           .FirstOrDefault();

        if (toolObject != null)
        { ... }
    }
}
```

Note that the error occurred when the `toolObject` variable is declared.

I used a trick to *solve* that exception by storing the `dbTool.ToolDefinitionId.Id` into a variable before using it in LINQ expression:

```
var toolDefnitionId = dbTool.ToolDefinitionId.Id;
var toolObject = toolTable
    .Where(toolObj => toolObj.ToolDefinition_Id == toolDefnitionId)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (toolObject != null)
{ ... }
```

Any idea why?